# Is there a way to get postfix to accept mail for a domain rewrite the address then smtp the mail out to the real MX for that address?

Tags: postfix

We're using virtual_alias_domains to tell postfix we handle the domain and virtual_alias_maps to rewrite the address we want to forward to.

But in some cases, the rewritten address has the same domain, but we don't handle it (and we're not the mx for that domain, the mail gets forwarded to us in the first place via a hardcoded method that doesn't do mx lookups).

So basically I want postfix to accept the mail for the domain example.com do a virtual_alias_maps lookup, which returns (for example) test@example.com and then forward the mail to the real mx for example.com.

I've tried a bunch of things, but it seems as long as example.com is in our virtual_alias_domains list (which it has to be or postfix won't accept the mail in the first place) I can't get it to try and send the email out via the real mx.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach, which does work, is to create "Transport Mappings" for those domains to forward off to either:

- One of the identified MX host for the destination domain
- Another SMTP host to complete the actual delivery

The first approach is basically "hardwiring" based on a point-in-time MX configuration for the actual destination domain (which may change over time).

The second approach will facilitate the "regular" SMTP delivery via live DNS lookups, but will require an additional SMTP host/relay partner.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. Unfortunately I can't test it without setting up another smtp server which is out of scope at the moment.

Comment: You can try option 1 to get things off the ground and then consider option 2 for the long run...

Comment: well, I tried. numerous times. I can't put in any transport map setting that in any way seems to affect the outcome. It does the virtual alias map lookup, gets the forwarding address, then tries to look that up in the virtual alias map, and fails, and doesn't make any attempt to use any transportmap I specify. It just gives up. I don't get it.

Comment: Is it in the format of "domain.name   smtp:[destination]" within /etc/postfix/transport?

Comment: well, I thought it mattered what you put in main.cf as in... fallback_transport = dbm:/etc/postfix/transportmapfile

Comment: but I added it to the transport file as well. Nada. I'm sure I'm missing something pretty basic. But it's escaping me.

Comment: What does your actual entry look like? Can you share a peek?

Comment: This is my test system, so I have it accepting mail for yahoo.com I've tried this... 

.yahoo.com smtp:[yahoo.com]
and this....   .yahoo.com smtp:g.mx.mail.yahoo.com

Comment: and various others. It just doesn't even seem to be noticing that theres another transport option after it fails the virtual map lookup

Comment: Can you try - "yahoo.com smtp:[74.6.136.244]" and see if it does any better? If it still doesn't work for you, then it's leaning hard on option 2...

Comment: Same thing. I've got the postfix logging turned all the way up and there's nothing in all the debug logs that show any attempt at the transport lookup. I don't think option 2 will work any differently, because I can't get postfix to notice that there's another way to route the mail. Argh. Thanks for your time. Any other ideas are appreciated.

Comment: One last try... Does your /etc/postfix/main.cf contain a "transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport" entry and maybe "relay_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/transport" as well?

Comment: Jun 10 09:17:50 barbuda postfix/qmgr[16201]: [ID 947731 mail.crit] fatal: unsupported dictionary type: hash
 well that's weird, but I made it a dbm, and it didn't help.

Comment: There isn't even a comment about putting transport_maps in main.cf  Postfix for all of it's wonderfulness and detailed documentation is really lacking in some ways. the hash type not supported thing makes me curious. I wonder if this is a really old version of postfix. we keep production up to date, but this is an old test system I'm working with. wouldn't that be a kick in the head. one moment.

Comment: It's 2.8.2. oh well. I thought it might be something simple like an old version.

Comment: You might try swapping out "hash" for "dbm" or just directly referencing /etc/postfix/transport to see if either works.

Comment: yeah when I saw that error, I switched to dbm, postmapped the file, restarted, no change.

Comment: If you can, it might be worth rebuilding another postfix fresh to see if it is something specific to the current one.

Comment: yeah, we're kind of going out of scope there. I'm a developer, I can't commission things like that... Thanks for keeping involved. If anything else hits you, lemme know, thanks.

Comment: Will do, but hopefully your engineering counterparts can respond to what you need and what you are currently running into...